# Compare fields from the query results in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am in a scenario to obtain all the records from a table where FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME of a particular record is the same but the BIRTHDATE is greater than or equal to 15 years.

Consider my table looks like:

```
_______________________________________________________________________________
| PRIMARY_ID | UNIQUE_ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | SUFFIX | BIRTHDATE          |
_______________________________________________________________________________
| 12345      | abcd      | john      | collin   | Mr     | 1975-10-01 00:00:00|
| 12345      | cdef      | john      | collin   | Mr     | 1960-10-01 00:00:00|
| 12345      | efgh      | john      | collin   | Mr     | 1975-10-01 00:00:00|
| 12345      | ghij      | john      | collin   | Mr     | 1960-10-01 00:00:00|
| 12345      | aaaa      | john      | collin   | Mr     | 1975-10-01 00:00:00|
| 12345      | bdfs      | john      | collin   | Mr     | 1975-10-01 00:00:00|
| 12345      | asdf      | john      | collin   | Mr     | null               |
| 12345      | dfgh      | john      | collin   | Mr     | null               |
| 23456      | ghij      | jeremy    | lynch    | Mr     | 1982-10-15 00:00:00|
| 23456      | aaaa      | jacob     | lynch    | Mr     | 1945-10-12 00:00:00|
| 23456      | bdfs      | jeremy    | lynch    | Mr     | 1945-10-12 00:00:00|
| 23456      | asdf      | jacob     | lynch    | Mr     | null               |
| 23456      | dfgh      | jeremy    | lynch    | Mr     | null               |
_______________________________________________________________________________
```

In this table, for the PRIMARY_ID 12345, the FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME are all same but the BIRTHDATE difference between the UNIQUE_IDs if 15 years. So this PRIMARY_ID needs to be pulled out. Wherein for PRIMARY_ID 23456, the FIRSTNAME is not the same for all UNIQUE_ID records, so it must not be pulled out.

The table might contain NULL values for BIRTHDATE, which should be ignored.

This is what I have tried till now:

```
SELECT
  /*PARALLEL(16)*/
  PRIMARY_ID,
  UNIQUE_ID,
  FIRSTNAME,
  LASTNAME,
  SUFFIX,
  BIRTHDATE,
  RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SUFFIX, BIRTHDATE) "GROUP"
FROM TABLE;
```

I have queried to form separate groups to distinguish by FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME and BIRTHDATE. I do not know on how to proceed further with this.

Can someone please help out?

**NOTE**: The BIRTHDATE field is in varchar datatype and I use Oracle 12C.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Given the BIRTHDATE field is a VARCHAR, is it uniform in its format?  Always YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS ?

Comment: Yes @alexgibbs.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  One other question.  Are you looking for primary_id 12345 to be included twice (once for abcd + cdef and once for efgh + ghij), or just one time to represent all cases?

Comment: One time to represent all classes @alexgibbs. The query I shared is just to view the correctness of my query through results.

Comment: Thanks Mike, and apologies for multiple questions.  A couple more though -- are you only interested in situations where adjacent unique_id are different by 15+ years, or any in the group.  For example if abcd were 1960 and cdef were 1970 and efgh were 1975 and ghij were 1980, should this be considered a match or not?  Also, when you say nulls can be ignored, did you mean they should count as non-matches, or not even compared?

Comment: You're right. I missed to provide that info ! I need records only when adjacent unique_id are different by 15+ years. And when on null, they should not be compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the goal is to return the distinct set of `primary_id` for which adjacent (alphabetically) `unique_id` that share the same `firstname` and `lastname` are separated by 15+ years.  As I understand it, `NULL` should interrupt comparison (and be considered a non-match (otherwise, primary_id 23456 would also match here for pseudo-adjacent `bdfs` + `ghij`).

There are other ways to do this, but one way available in 12c is to use pattern-matching.  An example is below.  The example just uses a difference of 5478 days as to represent 15-years, but one could nuance that if greater exactitude was needed for intercalary days etc.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRIMARY_ID
FROM THE_TABLE
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        PARTITION BY PRIMARY_ID
        ORDER BY UNIQUE_ID
        ONE ROW PER MATCH
        AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
        PATTERN(FIFTEEN_DIFF)
        DEFINE FIFTEEN_DIFF AS
            (FIFTEEN_DIFF.FIRSTNAME = PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.FIRSTNAME)
                AND FIFTEEN_DIFF.LASTNAME = PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.LASTNAME)
                AND (ABS(EXTRACT( DAY FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - PREV(TO_TIMESTAMP(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))))) >= 5478)));

Result:

  PRIMARY_ID
       12345


1 row selected.
```

The above query does the following:
`PARTITION`s to look at each `PRIMARY_ID` group individually,

then `ORDER`s by the `UNIQUE_ID`, so only alphabetically-adjacent records are compared.

Then each record is compared to the last, and if they share `FIRSTNAME` and `LASTNAME`, and their `BIRTHDATE`s differ by 15+ years, they are counted as a `MATCH`, and returns one record to indicate this.

After any match is found, it skips to the next row and resumes comparing.

Since only the distinct matches are desired, a `DISTINCT` is included in the select statement.

**EDIT:**

In response to follow-up questions, adding two additional examples.

**Alternative 1: Pre-Filter `NULL`**
This will bring different `UNIQUE_ID` into proximity, giving different matches.

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRIMARY_ID
FROM (SELECT PRIMARY_ID, UNIQUE_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, SUFFIX, BIRTHDATE
      FROM THE_TABLE
      WHERE BIRTHDATE
          IS NOT NULL)
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        PARTITION BY PRIMARY_ID
        ORDER BY UNIQUE_ID
        ONE ROW PER MATCH
        AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
        PATTERN (FIFTEEN_DIFF)
        DEFINE FIFTEEN_DIFF AS
            (FIFTEEN_DIFF.FIRSTNAME = PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.FIRSTNAME)
                AND FIFTEEN_DIFF.LASTNAME = PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.LASTNAME)
                AND (ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') -
                                           PREV(TO_TIMESTAMP(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))))) >= 5478)));
```

Result (this now includes `PRIMARY_ID` 23456, as removing NULL brings two `UNIQUE_ID`s into order that ar 15+ years apart) :

```
  PRIMARY_ID
       12345
       23456

2 rows selected.
```

**Alternative 2: Count NULL as a match**

```
SELECT DISTINCT PRIMARY_ID
FROM THE_TABLE
    MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
        PARTITION BY PRIMARY_ID
        ORDER BY UNIQUE_ID
        ONE ROW PER MATCH
        AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST LAST ROW
        PATTERN (FIFTEEN_DIFF)
        DEFINE FIFTEEN_DIFF AS
            (FIFTEEN_DIFF.FIRSTNAME = PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.FIRSTNAME)
                AND FIFTEEN_DIFF.LASTNAME = PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.LASTNAME)
                AND ((ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM (TO_TIMESTAMP(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') -
                                           PREV(TO_TIMESTAMP(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))))) >= 5478)
                OR (LEAST(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE,PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE)) IS NULL
                        AND COALESCE(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE,PREV(FIFTEEN_DIFF.BIRTHDATE)) IS NOT NULL))));
```

Result (This also return both `PRIMARY_ID`, as `NULL` is now counted as a match):

```
  PRIMARY_ID
       12345
       23456


2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @alexgibbs. This explanation is one of a resource ! This query is running now. Meanwhile, I would like to know on the performance of this query. Because, my table holds close to 8 million records. Will this be a good option in terms of performance (by the amount of time consumed to return records)?

Comment: Thanks @Mike.  Performance is always an interesting question; there can be tradeoffs between performance/maintainence/readability, and within the performance realm there are oft tradeoffs between scalability/resource-usage/clock-time.  I've wished there were mechanisms here in SO to spawn new, less structured child-questions in a looser context where bigger data could be tested/discussed in an ongoing forum (a bit like code golf etc).  Anyway pattern-matching will need to do a full-scan, but it is not mechanically so different from aggregation.  Is this a one-time check, or daily?

Comment: I completely accept. This could be a weekly check. And don't forget, you're great !

Comment: Another question is that, you have not compared for null BIRTHDATE fields. Consider a default field value `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. What in case if I have to exclude comparing for this BIRTHDATE value too?

Comment: Thanks @Mike.  I apologize if I missed something, but I don't quite understand this follow-up.  I asked about `NULL`-handling before answering, and was under the impression from your response "And when on null, they should not be compared." and from the example results you posted that nulls should be present but not be compared.  If that is not the case, `NULL` could of course be pre-filtered out, but that would bring different `UNIQUE_ID` into line and give different results.  Or `NULL` could be treated as a match, etc. as you need.  Can you elaborate, or perhaps give an additional example?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion @alexgibbs. In the table provided, there are few null BIRTHDATE fields. Similarly, there could also be BIRTHDATE like `1900-01-01 00:00:00` or `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. All such fields should not be used for comparing the 15 years difference. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I'm completely new to the keywords like 'AFTER MATCH SKIP PAST..' So, is there any apt location where we can pre-filter such BIRTHDATE values?

Comment: Thanks @Mike.  Sure thing they can be cleanly filtered.  The pre-filter can be done just like ever with a `WHERE` clause applied before the pattern-matching is invoked.  I'll update with an example that shows this, and an example that shows treating NULL as a match.

Comment: @Mike Ok two additional examples added, to count NULL as a match, or to pre-filter NULL.  Thanks